# sorting DataFrame by columns using python

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a dataframe

```
df =
| CHROM | 
| ------| 
| chr1  | 
| chr5  |
| chr12 |
| chr9  |
| chr3  |
```

I have used this code to sort them:

```
sorted_df = df.sort_values(by=["CHROM"])
```

I got the result,

```
| CHROM | 
| ------| 
| chr1  | 
| chr12 |
| chr3  |
| chr5  |
| chr9  |
```

But, My expected output

```
| CHROM | 
| ------| 
| chr1  | 
| chr3  |
| chr5  |
| chr9  |
| chr12 |
```

Please suggest how to do using python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split base `"chr"` then sort the base number as `int` and find the index and return df with the sorted index.

```
idx = df["CHROM"].str.split('chr').str[-1].astype(int).sort_values().index
df_new = df.iloc[idx]
print(df_new)
```

Or You can use [`pandas.DataFrame.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with `key`.

```
df.sort_values(by=['CHROM'], 
               key=lambda x: df['CHROM'].str.split('chr').str[-1].astype(int))
```

Output:

```
   CHROM
0   chr1
4   chr3
1   chr5
3   chr9
2  chr12
```